# Ubuntu 20.04 broken gdm on wake up from suspend mode

Tags: nvidia, suspend, gdm

I'm using a desktop with Ubuntu 20.04 and a Nvidia RTX 2070 with driver "nvidia-driver-470". Sometimes when SO goes to suspend mode, on wake up GDM come back broken [like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewiKh.png).

So I need to run this command to GDM works again:
`sudo systemctl restart gdm`